# How to link data from one table to another using Laravel 4?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a customers migration table

```
Schema::create('customers', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('address');
    $table->string('phone');
    $table->string('email');
});
```

and a tripsheet migration table which goes like this

```
Schema::create('tripsheets', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('tripsheet_num');
    $table->integer('customer_id');
    $table->string('date');
    $table->string('customer_name');
    $table->string('customer_address');
    $table->string('customer_phone');
    $table->string('rep_address');
    $table->string('rep_phone');
});
```

I have also created a customer eloquent,

```
class Customer extends Eloquent {

    public $timestamps = true;
    public $table = 'customers';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'address', 'phone', 'email'];

    public function tripsheets(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Tripsheet', 'name', 'address', 'phone');
    }
}
```

and a tripsheet model,

```
class Tripsheet extends Eloquent {

    public $timestamps = true;
    public $table = 'tripsheets';
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function customer(){
        return $this->hasMany('Customer', 'name', 'address', 'phone');
    }
}
```

and my routes.php goes like this,

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});

Route::controller('/customers', 'CustomerController');
Route::controller('/tripsheets', 'TripsheetController');
```

I would like to link the customer_name, customer_address, customer_phone from the tripsheet table to the name, address, phone of the customer table. I also want to know how to route them and fetch them as a json data to be used by angular JS to display the result.

now should i create a third table to link these two? Or should i call it with `Customer::with('tripsheets')->all();`in the routes/controller?

I also want to know how to route them and fetch them as a json data to be used by angular JS to display the result.?

Comment: What do you want? You already linked the tripsheet with an customer..

Comment: but it doesnt seem to be working

Comment: i want to know how to link data from the tripsheets table like customer_name, customer_address, customer_phone to be linked to the name, address, phone of the customer table...?                              This is not getting linked automatically...I dont know where i've made the mistake...

Comment: and also where to route them in order for me to fetch the json data and output using Angular JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overlooked your code and after user315.. answer I see the problem. The `belongsTo` and `hasMany` has wrong arguments.

You need to change your code to the following to make it work:

```
class Customer extends Eloquent {
    public function tripsheets(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Tripsheet', 'tripsheet_num');
    }
}

class Tripsheet extends Eloquent {
    public function customer(){
        return $this->hasMany('Customer', 'tripsheet_num');
    }
}
```

The problem is that you have the field `tripsheet_num` in the table `tripsheets`. Laravel tries to find a field called `tripsheet_id` inside the tripsheets table when you use the `belongsTo(Tripsheet)` on `Customer`. In your case this key field is named different and is not found, and so the relation is not set.

Same goes for `hasMany()` only then it looks in the other table for the key field.

See the relation documentation for more info: [One-to-one relation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#one-to-one) & [hasMany](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many)

Answer (score 0):

You only need the first argument in your `belongsTo` and `hasMany` method.  The others are likely the reason why it's not working.  They are meant for telling Eloquent what the foreign key is, and if you are specifying the foreign key as `name`, then it's obviously not going to work right.

Since you have proper naming conventions, Eloquent can accurately guess what they should be and you shouldn't need them.